# Showing blank rows for filters in Yii2.0 with GridView

Tags: php, yii

I have set up GridView to crfeate my table in Yii2.0 as follows:

```
<?= \yii\grid\GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $model->dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $model->searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'label' => Yii::t( $cat, 'Id' ),
            'value' => 'id',
        ],
        [
            'label' => Yii::t( $cat, 'Title' ),
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ( $data ) {
                if ( $data['status_code'] != 5 )
                {
                    return Html::a( $data['title'], '/signer/view/' . $data['id'] );
                }
                else
                {
                    return $data['title'];
                }
            },
        ],
        [
            'label' => Yii::t( $cat, 'Description' ),
            'value' => 'description',
        ],
        [
            'label' => Yii::t( $cat, 'Filename' ),
            'value' => 'filename',
        ],
        [
            'label' => Yii::t( $cat, 'Status' ),
            'value' => 'status',
            'contentOptions' => function ( $data ) {
                    $statuses = [
                        1 => 'text-primary',    # New
                        2 => 'text-warning',    # Unsigned
                        3 => 'text-warning',    # Partially signed
                        4 => 'text-success',    # Signed
                        5 => 'text-danger',     # Deleted
                    ];
                    return [ 'class' => $statuses[$data['status_code']] ];
                }
        ],
        [
            'label' => Yii::t( $cat, 'Created' ),
            'value' => 'created',
        ],
        //[ 'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn' ],
    ],
]);
?>
```

I get all the correct data, but instead of filter inputs, I get empty rows.

[image]

**Why is that? What am I missing?**

PS: The search model itself works fine, meaning, when I add to the url `?title=asd` it actually get the search results!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation of the `$filterModel`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html#$filterModel-detail) property:

> Note that in order to show an input field for filtering, a column must have its `yii\grid\DataColumn::$attribute` property set or have `yii\grid\DataColumn::$filter` set as the HTML code for the input field.

So you need to set `yii\grid\DataColumn::$attribute` property on your columns and in most of the cases this makes the `value` unnecessary:

```
<?= \yii\grid\GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $model->dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $model->searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'label' => Yii::t( $cat, 'Id' ),
            'attribute' => 'id',
        ],
        [
            'label' => Yii::t( $cat, 'Title' ),
            'format' => 'raw',
            'attribute' => 'title',
            'value' => function ( $data ) {
                if ( $data['status_code'] != 5 )
                {
                    return Html::a( $data['title'], '/signer/view/' . $data['id'] );
                }
                else
                {
                    return $data['title'];
                }
            },
        ],
        [
            'label' => Yii::t( $cat, 'Description' ),
            'attribute' => 'description',
        ],
        [
            'label' => Yii::t( $cat, 'Filename' ),
            'attribute' => 'filename',
        ],
        [
            'label' => Yii::t( $cat, 'Status' ),
            'attribute' => 'status',
            'contentOptions' => function ( $data ) {
                    $statuses = [
                        1 => 'text-primary',    # New
                        2 => 'text-warning',    # Unsigned
                        3 => 'text-warning',    # Partially signed
                        4 => 'text-success',    # Signed
                        5 => 'text-danger',     # Deleted
                    ];
                    return [ 'class' => $statuses[$data['status_code']] ];
                }
        ],
        [
            'label' => Yii::t( $cat, 'Created' ),
            'attribute' => 'created',
        ],
        //[ 'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn' ],
    ],
]);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. No idea how I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible reason for the blank line: (not in posters exact case)

Missing/incorrect declaration of the `public function rules()` in the search model. In Yii 1 you could concatenate the string, in Yii2 they need to be actual array elements.

```
return [
    [['authorId, title, publishFrom'], 'safe'],       //WRONG
    [['authorId', 'title', 'publishFrom'], 'safe'],   //CORRECT
];
```

Comment: And if you are using the filterModel property the model used there must extend yii\base\Model.